# Successor / alternatives to 2D XNA?

Tags: windows, winforms, xna, microsoft-metro

It looks like Microsoft is backing away from XNA (but not DirectX): (see http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-false-alarm-we-arent-backing-away-from-directx-7000010647/, note that there is no XNA Game Studio / XNA available for the new Visual Studio 2012, etc).

What technology can be used in it's place, for a 2D, managed game on Windows?  I'd love to find something that works on Windows 7 and 8, with bonus points for WinXP and/or WinPhone.

I apologize for the overly broad question, but I've dug around in the MS website & can't seem to find any clear guidance.  Silverlight looks promising, but I can't tell if that's going to be phased out too.  It looks like Metro apps should prefer to use JavaScript, but I can't tell if you can use C#/.Net with that.  WinForms would be great, but I think that's also "the past, not the future"

Any guidance would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried monogame
[MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/)
Its latest version also supports WP8

Answer (score 1):

[SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) are managed wrappers for the DirectX API.

While future-proof, neither of them is an elaborate game development framework like XNA. You would have to implement important features like sprite rendering, content management, etc. by yourself.